# MySQL refuses to connect when two instances of mysql created in win10 and ubuntu (dualboot)?

Tags: mysql, windows, ubuntu-19.04

I'm running a dualboot system on the same ssd(one partition for Ubuntu 19.04, one for windows 10 home 1903). Both currently have MySQL 8.0 installed on them, with the same 'root' user and same password.

**Before I installed mysql on ubuntu,** I ran a single instance of mysql on Windows 10for my projects perfectly fine(workbench, terminal(cmd, rather) could both connect to root)

Then i installed ubuntu and(stupidly) named the mysql server user as 'root' as well, with the same password.

And now both mysql in both OS refuses to connect with the error:

```
"Error Nr. 1045 access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"
```

Trying `mysql -u root` wouldnt work either, throwing the error

```
"Error Nr. 1045 access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"
```

I'd really love to know why this error occurs and how I could possibly run two instances on two OS's(in the first place when the Ubuntu is shut down that instance isnt running nor listening on 3306 anymore, so why should this error occur?)

Password is definitely correct and the standard google search replies to reset the password didnt change anything either.

Thanks! :)

Comment: If you shut one down does it start working? Shouldn't be an issue that they have the same user/password. I'm guessing it's a permissions issue. Are you accessing mysql locally on both machines or using ssh/rdp?

Comment: I did that in Ubuntu plus edited /etc/mysql.conf to comment out "#bind address = 127.0.0.1" and restarted mysql in Ubuntu which did the trick ON UBUNTU SIDE. When i booted back to windows mysql was still inaccessible at all costs. Uninstalling mysql in Windows 10 right now to see if that works. I'm posting this question only because I am super intrigued as to how this error happened since I only lost access to mysql server AFTER i started running mysql in Ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

Did your mysql on Ubuntu and Window shared the same data directory ? Anyway, what worked for me is reinstall mysql on both platforms

Comment: They shouldnt share the same data directory since both are on separate partitions of the drive, i suppose

Comment: Completely different filesystems as well.